# magento 2 - need to add cart page in checkout step

Tags: magento2

[image]I need to add cart page in checkout steps the same as uploaded image, step 1 is cart page step 2 is shipping and step 3 is a payment.
can anyone help me to do this in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the normal scenario you already have a cart page (/checkout/cart/).
I would say that you change the layout of that page to match the other 2 and you have the desired effect.